# Multiple devs using Xdebug remotely with PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

In my team, multiple developers are working on a same remote server. When they need to debug, they use *Xdebug* with *PhpStorm*.

Remote debugging works fine with a single developer, but **multiple developers can't use *Xdebug* at the same time**: when they try to do so, problems start to occur (typically, freezing).

I have two basic questions:

1. is it mandatory that the PhpStorm Xdebug options match exactly the remote server's php.ini options (`xdebug.remote_port` and so on)?
2. I'm aware that using *DBGp Proxy* should help in my use case. **But** on the remote dev server, only one `php.ini` file exists. May this be the cause of the problem? I mean, after each developer has set his personal `xdebug.idekey` value into his own *PhpStorm* client, how can multiple debugging sessions can run together knowing that there's only one `php.ini` file on the remote server and therefore only **one** `xdebug.idekey` matching value? Of course this question is related to the previous one...

Thank you

Comment: Use **DBGp Proxy** -- it meant just for that and PhpStorm supports it. Official article: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Multi-user+debugging+in+PhpStorm+with+Xdebug+and+DBGp+proxy . If you don't want to use it -- `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` may help (as long as server is on LAN (same network) and devs have own computers.

Comment: *"how could the server handle multiple Xdebug connections?"* Please read the xdebug manual first. Thing is -- server does not handle any xdebug connections -- xdebug connects to client (PhpStorm in your case) and not other way around. So xdebug can initiate many connections, as long as web server can establish that many workers.

Comment: *"do the PhpStorm Xdebug options have to match exactly the remote server's php.ini options (xdebug.remote_port and so on)"* Yes, as it's xdebug that connects to IDE and not other way around. So PhpStorm MUST listen correct port in order to receive the incoming xdebug session.

Comment: @LazyOne thank you for your comments. You're right, I didn't fully read the doc, since I'm only starting to grab some infos about the issue. 
You wrote _Use DBGp Proxy_ and I'm indeed aware of it. In fact, I wrote my second question in that sense. That is, after each developer has set his own PhpStorm client and thus set his personal `xdebug.idekey` value, how can it work knowing that there's only *one php.ini file* on the remote server, thus only one `xdebug.idekey` matching value? I hope I clear enough.

Comment: I have never used DBGp Proxy myself (haver had a need) so cannot give precise answer. But according to the article I gave the link to only IDE Key on developer side should be unique, the one on server should not matter (you may leave it empty). Plus, PhpStorm does not really care about IDE Key value -- I can set it to be "Eclipse" in PhpStorm settings and "NetBeans" in php.ini and it will still work (I'm using "zero-config" approach)

Comment: @LazyOne you should answer the question so we can upvote that instead

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work in your environment, but having multiple dev's using Xdebug with PHPStorm works just fine in our environment.  I know that's not an answer to your question, but I wanted to make sure you know it **IS** possible.

Comment: @Erutan409 thanks for your comment. Indeed, I know it's possible :) BTW how did you configure each PhpStorm client in your environment ? I guess you configured the DBGp Proxy settings, but how did you manage exactly to make things work ?